# Non-trivial conversion of svn to mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial

We have the following SVN structure:

```
trunk
  -- A
    -- x
    -- y
  -- B
  -- C
branches
  -- b1
    -- x
    -- y
  ...
tags
  -- t1
    -- x
    -- y
  ...
```

Meaning, we have 3 folders under the trunk, but the branches and tags are created only from the A folder, and contain only its content.
We are now trying to migrate this to mercurial. What we would really like to have is 3 repositories for A, B and C, where the A repository has the trunk and all the branches and tags.
Is there a way to do this? I have tried the following:

- Excluding B and C - I still get the A folder, which I don't want.
- Including A and renaming it to . - I get the A repository as I want, but no branches or tags
- Using convert.svn.trunk=trunk/A - I still get folders B and C

If there is no way to do this conversion, is there at least a way where I can get a working copy that contains only part of the repository (e.g. trunk/A, but without the A folder itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define missing parameters for solutions 2:

except --filemap (`include trunk/A` + `rename trunk/A .`) add `svn.branches` and `svn.tags`

*Slightly different* solution may be

- clone the whole repository with hgsubversion (with `--layout auto`)
- strip unwanted parts with convert and it's --filemap

Comment: This is the command I used (I hope I understood correctly):

    hg convert --filemap hg_filemap.txt --config convert.svn.branches=branches --config convert.svn.tags=tag svn://tlvsvn c:\hg_test.

This is the content of the filemap:

include A
rename A .

When I look at the result the default branch looks fine, but I only see a relatively small number of branches, and no tags.

Am I running the command as intended? I tried using trunk/A in the filemap, but that imported an empty repository.